# How do I color background based on 1 or 0 in Python

Tags: python, background

I want the background of the graph of x to be grey when y=1 and white when y=0

```
    #some random data
    x = np.random.random(12)
    #0's and 1's
    y = [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

    plt.plot(np.linspace(0, 12, 12), x);
```

[So it looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnzuT.png) in stead of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOr90.png)

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is not clear what you are asking without knowing what these additional variables are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try manually drawing the rectangles using a loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np

idx = np.linspace(0, 12, 12)
x = np.random.random(12)
y = [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(idx, x)

rect_height = np.max(x)
rect_width = 1

for i, draw_rect in enumerate(y):
    if draw_rect:
        rect = patches.Rectangle(
            (i, 0),
            rect_width,
            rect_height,
            linewidth=1,
            edgecolor='grey',
            facecolor='grey',
            fill=True
        )
        ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

[image: Output figure]